# The gradient of a convex function is controlled by its oscillation on a larger ball

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

My problem is

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow R$ be a convex function. Knowing
>   that $$|\nabla f(x)|=\sup_{y\neq x}\frac{[f(x)-f(y)]^+}{|x-y|}$$
>   ($[f(x)-f(y)]^+$ represents $\max\{[f(x)-f(y)],0\}$) prove that for
>   any $0< r\leq R$ we have  $$(R-r)\max_{|x|\leq r}|\nabla f(x)|\leq \max_{x\leq R}f(x)-\min_{|x|\leq R}f(x).$$

It may be useful that in the proof of the given hint, it turns out that the $\sup$ can be taken over $y\neq x,y$ in a neighbourhood of $x$ (any neighbourhood).

General suggestions of tools regarding convex functions are welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a point $x_0$ and a nearby point $y_)$ so that the ratio $s = [f(x_0)-f(y_0)]^+/|x_0-y_0|$ is close to $\max_{|x|\le r}|\nabla f(x)|$. Draw the line through $x_0,y_0$ and consider the restriction of $f$ to this line, denoted $g$. Since $g$ is convex, its graph lies above its secant line except between the points where the line meets the graph. So, along the half-line that continues the segment $[x_0,y_0]$ beyond $x_0$, the values of $f$ are bounded from below by a linear function with the slope of $s$.

Going along  this half-line until it exists the ball $|x|\le R$, we see the values of the linear function increase by at least $(R-r)s$. Hence, $$\max_{|x|\le R}f\ge f(x_0)+(R-r)s $$
and the result follows.